# Changing look of segue arrows

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Maybe it is a silly question. But is there a way to change the path the segue arrows take in the storyboard?

Because i have quite a lot of controllers and views and it is hard to see all the segues. And my app is not finished there are more views still to come.

I have not found a way to change the path of the arrows other than changing the place of the controller it comes from or goes to. That makes it worst most of the time.

Greeting Adarkas

Comment: Well, this is the first time I've heard someone ask for a solution to this, despite the fact that many (if not all) devs are bothered by this. But what can you expect, when trying to visualise a directed graph (of sorts) in a 2D space? Let's see if someone has a solution.

Comment: Most systems that work in a UML type design have the ability to remap the connections between nodes. Look at UE4's blueprint editor for example.